# PartitionOfflineException getting spring + geode + kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

**Setup:**

- spring boot 2.7.8
- geode version: 1.14.4

I have one service (app) with PARTITION_PROXY region and second one (cache) with PARTITION_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW. Both are running as separated pods in kubernetes.

**Problem:**
When i patch those services , kubernetes let old ones running and parallely starts new ones. When new ones are ready , then terminate old ones. This process is running simultaneously for both services. But somehow in this process new service(app) remebers old service (cache ). Im getting this exception:

Exception:
Region /REGION_NAME bucket 89 has persistent data that is no longer online stored at these locations

**Question:**
How would you solve this? I mean the way so i can stick with parallel deployment. Is there configuration which say "forget offline partitioned buckets" ? Can i force service (app) to forget offline bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke a missing diskstore, however that may cause lost data. See https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-GemFire/9.15/tgf/GUID-tools_modules-gfsh-command-pages-revoke.html.

I suggest looking at the GemFire for Kubernetes operator which handles rolling upgrades with no data loss.

https://network.tanzu.vmware.com/products/tanzu-gemfire-for-kubernetes/